# How does "for" work in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

I am completely new to scala programming and trying to understand a function written (functional programming) by our architect. How can I understand the `for` loop?

```
def checkS3BValidity(rows: Vector[Map[String, Object]]): Vector[Map[String, Object]] = {

val s3 = List("app_code", "s3_access_key", "s3_secret_key", "s3_primary_bkt_name")
val excludeList = new ListBuffer[String]

for (elem <- rows map (row => s3 map row)) {
  val elem_str = elem.map(_.toString)

  logger.info("verifying the S3 bucket passed from the ctrl table for each App")
  logger.info(s"Checking on App Code: ${elem head}")

  listS3Buckets(elem_str(1), elem_str(2)) match {

    case Some(allBktsInfo) =>
      logger.info(s"App: ${elem_str head} provided the bucket name as: ${elem_str(3)}")
      if (allBktsInfo.exists(x => x.getName == elem_str(3))) {
        logger.info(s"Provided S3 bucket: ${elem_str(3)} exists")
        println(s"s3 ${elem_str(3)} bucket exists")
      } else {
        logger.info(s"WARNING: Provided S3 bucket ${elem_str(3)} doesn't exists")
        logger.info(s"WARNING: Dropping the App: ${elem_str.head} from backup schedule")
        excludeList += elem_str.head // If the bucket is invalid then we exclude from backup
        println(s"s3 bucket ${elem_str(3)} doesn't exists")
    }

    case None =>
      logger.info(s"WARNING: Provided S3 bucket ${elem_str(3)} doesn't exists")
      logger.info(s"WARNING: Dropping the App: ${elem_str.head} from backup schedule")
      excludeList += elem_str.head // If the bucket is invalid then we exclude from backup
}

    logger.info(s"WARNING: Couldn't access these buckets: $excludeList")
rows filterNot (row => row.exists(m => excludeList.contains(m._2)))

  }
```

Comment: please ask for help regarding code rather than explaining logic. Also be specific in the part you don't understand

Answer (score 2):

It is very poorly written.  Using an `Object` is almost never recommended.  Using a mutable container like a `ListBuffer` isn't recommended in functional code.  Useful naming information about each row is thrown away.  I would write it something like:

```scala
def bucketExists(row: Map[String, String]): Boolean = {
  val buckets = listS3Buckets(row("s3_access_key"), row("s3_secret_key")) getOrElse List.empty[Bucket]
  val bucketNames = buckets map {_.getName}
  bucketNames contains row("s3_primary_bkt_name")
}

def getExistingBuckets(rows: Vector[Map[String, String]]): Vector[Map[String, String]] = {
  val (exists, missing) = rows partition bucketExists
  missing foreach {row =>
    logger.info(s"WARNING: Provided S3 bucket ${row("s3_primary_bkt_name")} doesn't exist")
    logger.info(s"WARNING: Dropping the App: ${row("app")} from backup schedule")
  }
  exists
}
```

This makes it much more clear that you're logging info about the buckets that don't exist and returning a list of only those buckets that do exist.

Answer (score -1):

As a resume, iterates over S3 Objects that are buckets and check if these buckets exists or not. Gives you a logger to check that and finally log all buckets that there are not in S3.